# How to create a Custom Circle?

Tags: iphone, geometry, nsobject

I want to create a custom circle for my application whose all attribute and property i want to define my self.

Basically i want to create a myCircle class which should be inherited from NSObject class.

How can i do that? 
Any sample application /example/ code for reference?

Answer (score 4):

#### MyCircle.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyCircle : NSObject
{
    // Declare properties here
    float radius;
}

@property (nonatomic) float radius;

- (id)initWithRadius:(float)r;

@end
```

#### MyCircle.m

```
#import "MyCircle.h"

@implementation MyCircle

@synthesize radius;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize
        [self setRadius:10.0]; // set a default value for radius
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithRadius:(float)r {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        [self setRadius:r];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

If you want to display a circle on a view based on your MyCircle object, you could subclass a UIView and override the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method. You can instantiate the circle using the `- (id)initWithRadius:(float)r` method.

If you're not sure how to go about doing any of that, I recommend reading an introductory book on iOS programming. I swear by [the Big Nerd Ranch guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_nd_edition_).

Comment: So for display this circle , do i have to create a custom view?

Comment: Ah, you never mentioned you wanted to draw the circle. I updated my answer.